# Email ingestion in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

We are storing incoming emails into hadoop using Java code (written by some other team). They were getting error into production where, lets say, 'To' field is not being displayed into HBase (Using for searching emails etc). As a part of support team, I have modified the java code to accept the 'bcc' field for pointforward emails but now they want to fix the issue for existing emails where 'bcc' field is missing.

Developer asked me to write a Map Reduce Job to fix this error but I have a very little knowledge of writing those jobs ... I can learn it but before moving ahead I want to know is this the only option to fix the issue Or Can I use other tools to fix this where learning curve is small?

Comment: The BCC field isn't part of an incoming email.

Comment: right..I just gave an example you can assume 'To' field .. I will update my post.

Comment: still your question is not clear about what you want to do with hbase, explain your data structure on existing hbase data a bit please.